# Issue with Apache Tez configuration

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, tez

I want to configure **apache tez** with **apache hadoop**. But getting below issue ... Anyone can suggest me how i can resolve this issue.

**Caused by:** org.apache.tez.dag.api.TezUncheckedException: Invalid configuration of tez jars, tez.lib.uris is not defined in the configuration

Comment: Have you checked the configuration to see what tez.lib.uris is set to?